# Repetitive usage of Java's SecureRandom

Tags: java, security, random, cryptography

I'm a little bit confused about the usage of `SecureRandom`. I need to generate *n* **secure** random numbers in a loop. Is it secure to use the same SecureRandom instance for each generation? Are there any difference between the solutions below in terms of cryptographic strength?

1) Single instance without seeding

```
SecureRandom sr = new SecureRandom();
for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) sr.nextInt();
```

2) New instance for each generation

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) new SecureRandom().nextInt();
```

3) Single instance with seeding

```
SecureRandom sr = new SecureRandom()
for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    byte[] seed = sr.generateSeed(32);
    sr.setSeed(seed);
    sr.nextInt();
}
```

Comment: *"I need to generate n random numbers in a loop"* - the first question is, do you need random numbers, or secure random numbers. If the former, then you don't need `SecureRandom`. You can use a [Linear Congruential Generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator). an LCG would be appropriate for simulations, where you need numbers fast from a uniform distribution.

Answer (score 12):

Perhaps counter-intuitively the third is almost certainly the weakest, reseeding on loop iteration is a terrible idea. The second is bad, but less bad, because the `SecureRandom()` includes a *strong* default seeding strategy. As asked, the first is almost certainly the most secure because it maximizes the entropic period. I suggest you extract it to a class level constant for that reason.

```
private static final Random RANDOM = new SecureRandom();
// ...
// your method,
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) { 
    int num = RANDOM.nextInt();
}
```

Comment: *"Perhaps counter-intuitively the third is almost certainly the weakest, reseeding on loop iteration is a terrible idea..."* - there are a couple of papers that might disagree with you. The papers recommend reseeding the generator the instance before the generator is asked to produce bits.

Comment: *"second is bad, but less bad, because the SecureRandom() includes a strong default seeding strategy"* - proof by counter example: [Android SecureRandom](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/08/some-securerandom-thoughts.html). Always seed the generator before using it. Don't rely on others.

Comment: @jww I maintain it's still less bad then option 3.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you should read this interesting [article](http://www.cigital.com/justice-league-blog/2009/08/14/proper-use-of-javas-securerandom/)

In general, there is no need to create multiple instances of SecureRandom(), as @ElliottFrisch stated a `static final` is the most appropriate solution.

However, if you will use your SecureRandom for a huge sequence of random outputs, you should periodically reseed it to not allow malicious software to determine the seed and thus predict all future outputs.